# Dependency Injection with ES6 modules

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, es6-modules

I have a question about dependency injection and best practices when using ES6 modules which are meant to be created often.

```
// ProductModule.js

import {CartModule} from './CartModule.js';

export class ProductModule {
    constructor() {
        this.cartModule = new CartModule();
    }

    addToCartListener() {
        $('.product-add-cart')
            .on('click', (event) => {
                this.cartModule.addToCart(46773, 1);
            })
        ;
    }      
}

// CartModule.js

import {UserModule} from './UserModule.js';
import {OtherModule} from './OtherModule.js';

export class CartModule {
    constructor() {
        this.userModule = new UserModule();
        this.otherModule = new OtherModule();
    }

    addToCart(idProduct, quantity) {
        this.userModule.function();
        this.otherModule.function();

        console.log(idProduct, quantity);

        return true;
    }      
}
```

I definitely don't like what I have written here in my opinion.
Is there a better way to do that ?

Comment: What don't you like about your code? It seems pretty reasonable to me (except maybe for the method named `function()`, and the unused `event`). You might post on codereview if you don't have a specific question

Answer (score 2):

So, dependency injection removes the tight coupling between the ProductModule and CartModule in your case. You should inject the cart module in the constructor of the product module. Doing this will decouple your code.

```
constructor (private cart: CartModule) {}
```

Lets suppose in future you have 2 types of cart - wishlist cart and shopping cart. Then because you have used dependency injection in product module, you can pass any of the above cart into that and depending on that the product module will add the products to that cart.
This results in extensibility of the product module you have created.

Comment: Thanks for your answer !
But how I am supposed to instantiate modules (ProductModule in this case) with DI ?

    const cartModule = new CartModule();
    const productModule = new ProductModule(cartModule);

Comment: So.. you do not need to create a new instance in your application. If you are using this DI in Angular. you can call the methods of the cartModule simply this: 

this.cart.methodName();

Not sure about how it behaves in java or any other language. I guess in that case, you can instantiate the modules like : 

const cartModule = new CartModule();
As you mentioned.

Comment: You can export only classes's factory instead of direct class, take a look at the di-ninja library, there is many exemples of this